# function pcntl_exec() undefined but function exists

Tags: php, linux, pcntl

I am using Debian 9, Apache, PHP 7.0. When running command

```
php -r "pcntl_exec('/bin/bash','/tmp/1');"
```

is correct, but when I visit the PHP file in the browser, it shows me that

```
undefined function pcntl_exec()
```

Even I try to use the file below it is also right, it can run.

```
php -F "/var/www/html/pcntltest.php
```

I try to use `function_exists()`. When I run it in bash, is `true`, but in `php` result is `false`.

/var/www/html/1.php:

```
<?php pcntl_exec('/bin/bash','/tmp/1');?>
```

/tmp/1:

```
ls /
```

packages:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 

sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-json 
php7.0-cli php7.0-curl libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Comment: It's possible that the function is disabled (php.ini `disabled_functions`).

Comment: The php_cli doesn't use the same php.ini than the server one, execute the `phpinfo` function from a website and this way it will show you which php.ini is using and then you can try to add the `pnctl` extension in there. And remember to restart the server each time you update the php.ini file

Comment: just one php.ini,disabled_functions is null